# Function substr returns data type larger than stated

Tags: oracle, plsql

The pl/sql function substr, e.g. `substr('some text', 1, 4)` returns a data type
larger than 4 characters.

I have difficulties to understand why the following doesn't work:

```
rowTxt VARCHAR2(60);
rowTxt := substr(text, (pos + 1), 60);
```

All the time I got an exception

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Can anyone please give me some reason why?

Cheers Hilde

Comment: Thank you for edit my posting more readably!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this has to do with nls_length_semantics.

Varchar2(60) may mean 60 characters but it may also mean 60 bytes. If nls_length_semantics is set to BYTE it will mean 60 bytes.

SUBSTR(,1,60) will return 60 characters. If one or more of these characters uses more than 1 byte you get the exception.

To try this declare your string as VARCHAR2(60 CHAR).

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/character-semantics-and-globalization-9i.php

Comment: Thank you! If I declare the source string and the return string as varchar2(...char) it works. However the problem is that the source string is VARCHAR2(255 Byte). The cast function doesn't work or rather causes a compiler error. I need to save the result of substr to VARCHAR2(60 Byte).

Comment: Now I solved it by using only substrb, lengthb and so forth. Now I have no problems any more.
Thanks for your link!

Answer (score 1):

The size of the result is not inferred from the parameters. In many cases that would not be possible anyway.

Use Cast(substr(text, (pos + 1), 60) as varchar2(60)) to solve this.

Comment: Hello David! Thank you for helping and that information. When using the cast function I get another exception:
 rowTxt := cast( substr(text, (pos + 1), 60) AS VARCHAR2(60) );
RA-06550: line 13, column 62:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:. ) @ %

Comment: Are you sure the error is from that line of code? See examples http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm

Comment: Yes, I am confused as well! I will check it!